# How to find sleeping process in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, process

Is there any way to find sleeping processes in Ubuntu?

I can see `top` can list out number of sleeping processes, but I want them to be listed with their name.

Are there any commands for that?

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
ps o state,command axh | grep "^[SD]" | cut -b 3-
```

for listing commands of processes with an interruptable and uninterruptable sleep state.

- `ps` outputting only state and commands of all processes (`ax`) and `h` removes the header line.
- `grep` filters processes other than the two sleep states
- `cut` is used to remove the state output again.
- Optionally replace `command` with `ucmd` if you don't need the full name including all arguments.

This is probably suboptimal scripting here, but I couldn't find a quick way to have `ps` filtered for a specific state.

Comment: @Thor Thanks for you now removed comment. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could grab the information from top, which can be run in batch mode (`-b`).

```
top -bn1 | awk 'NR > 7 && $8 ~ /S|D/ { print $12 }'
```

- `-n1` top runs only once and exits.
- `NR > 7` skips header.
- `$8 ~ /S|D/` selects programs which are in state `D` or `S`.

Possible states are, from `top(1)`:

```
      'D' = uninterruptible sleep
      'R' = running
      'S' = sleeping
      'T' = traced or stopped
      'Z' = zombie
```

Comment: It chops off the first character of the process name; you need to put `cut -c40-41,62-` instead of `cut -c40-41,63-`

Comment: It is actually 63 here so using specific column numbers is unreliable. I switched the parsing over to `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -e S
```

will show you sleeping processes.

Comment: Uhm... no. It will show *all* processes by providing the `-e` option.

Comment: ps -e S does in fact give you all the processes that are in a Sleep state. Very helpful.

Comment: @rob of course it does, because it shows *all* processes ... including those not in a sleep state, which is what `-e` does. `S` is: "Sum up some information, such as CPU usage, from dead child processes into their parent." Nothing in this command line will filter out non-sleeping processes.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and `ps`

```
ps o pid,state,command | \
    awk ' {if ($2 == "T") {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","Sleeping",$1,$3};}'
```

---

*Example*

Start `mc` in a terminal, open a new terminal and start the commands below

```
kill -STOP $(pgrep mc)
ps o pid,state,command | \
    awk ' {if ($2 == "T") {printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n","Sleeping",$1,$3};}'
```

Output is

```
Sleeping    21668   mc
```